# rename ui file in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am working on a gui with guide in matlab. Inbetween I devided to name the file
different and renamed it. I also renamed all functions to the new filename in the .m file
and all objects in he .fig file.

However when I start the application I still see this error

```
??? Undefined function or method 'uiSchwingungen' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==>     
@(hObject,eventdata)uiSchwingungen('edit1_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

Where `uiSchwingungen` is the old not existing filename.

Where is this code section hidden (It is not in the .m file, and the .fig is binary)

Comment: Did you rename the file manually, or did you "save as..."?

Comment: I renamed in manually, and later renamed it again using save as after I had found out that renaming is problematic.

Comment: If i read it correctly you already 'broke' the file before you did the right thing. My recommendation would be to try save as on a working file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the `.fig` in GUIDE, right click on an element (like a button), go into property browser, look for the `CallBack` property, click on its field to edit it, and you will find the text saying

```
@(hObject,eventdata)uiSchwingungen('edit1_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

You will need to replace `uiSchwingungen` with the name name of that element (which will be in the Tag field of the Property Inspector).

Go through all the buttons, text boxes, etc., as this mistake probably will have occurred more than once.